# python picamera - using with PiYUVArray on stored images

Tags: python, camera, raspberry-pi

I'm using PiYUVArray to print the average of Y values of captured images, here's the code:

```
import ...

camera=PiCamera()
output=PiYUVArray(camera)
w=64
h=48
camera.resolution=(w,h)
camera.start_preview()
sleep(2)
while True:
    camera.capture(output,'yuv')
    y_data=numpy.empty((h,w),dtype=numpy.uint8)
    y_data=output.array[:h, :w, :1].flatten()
    sum=0
    for i in range(0,len(y_data),1):
        sum=sum+y_data[i]
    print('avg = '+str(sum/len(y_data)))
    output.truncate(0)
    sleep(10)
```

how can I run it on a stored image? also is there any difference between **output.truncate(0)** and **output.seek(0)** as both works?

**EDIT**
I managed to open the image, but this way I'm looping only a vertical row of pixels, and how do I read the Y values?

```
im=Image.open('1920x1080.jpg')
im=im.convert('YCbCr')
np_im=numpy.array(im)
flat=np_im[:1080, :1920, :1].ravel()
```

Comment: it seems it uses numpy array. You can use module `PIL` (`pillow`) to load image (jpg, png, etc.) and convert to numpy array.

Comment: in normal file `seek(0)` moves pointer to beginning of file and you can read the same data again without reopening file. You can read it also after you open it again - you don't loose your data. `truncate(0)` removes all data from file so it automatically move pointer to 0. But later you can't read it again.

Comment: Surely you can just use `camera.capture(output,'yuv')` then `mean = output.mean()`

Comment: @furas I'm having problems with PIL installation, so in my case truncate is better to free resources right?

Comment: @MarkSetchell I didn't understand

Comment: as I said you have numpy array and @MarkSetchell suggests you to use numpy's function to calculate `avg`

Comment: `PIL` has nothing to do with truncate. You ask how to run it on stored image. And I say you can use `PIL`/`pillow` to load image (jpg,png) stored on disk. PIL can convert it to numpy array so you can run it.

Comment: @furas I know , it was a side question , why mean() returns me a slightly different average?

Comment: I don't know why `mean()` gives different result. Maybe you calculate something different - you use `y_data`, not directly `output`. You could create some small array (so you calculate mean manually) and test it with `mean()` and your code.

Comment: @furas I was wrong, see update

Comment: You have array and use `np_im[x, y, z]` as before to get element. You can check size of first row `len(np_im[0])` and it should be `1920`. Check `np_im.shape` to get size `1920x1080x3`.

Comment: Try printing `np_im.shape` rather than `len(np_im)`.

Comment: yes printing np_im.shape I get (1920, 1080, 3), but are these the yuv values? because I didn't mention 'yuv' anywhere in my code

Comment: maybe I understood, using `flat=np_im[:1080, :1920, :1].ravel()` I assign to **flat** variable the list of Y (1st) values right?

Comment: sorry for the multiple comments, by default image opens in RGB so and I need to convert it using .convert('YCbCr') right?